# Не передается extras через Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Мне нужно **выполнить определенные действия** в активити запущенном через **Intent**, но по каким то причинам информация присоединенная к интенту (в которой указано, что нужно выполнить) не передается. При запуске активити `getIntent()` всегда равен `null`. Не могу разобраться почему.

Так выглядит *первый* активити, из которого идет запуск второго:

```
public class Registration extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...
    public void clickCloseButton(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("startOperation", "DialogCloseRegistration");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    ...
}
```

Так выглядит *второй* активити, в котором нужно выполнить действия после его запуска:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Действие при запуске активити
        String operation = getIntent().getStringExtra("startOperation");
        if (operation != null) {
            if (operation.equals("DialogCloseRegistration")) {
                DialogFragment closeRegistration = new CloseRegistration();
                closeRegistration.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "closeRegistration");
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Так выглядят настройки *второго* запускаемого активити в манифесте:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
    android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="site.ru"
                android:pathPrefix="/sms"
                android:scheme="http" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

У *первого* активити никаких настроек нет, кроме портретного режима.

Возможно это не важно, но `MainActivity` уже запускался до того как был запущен `Registration`.

Comment: может вы неправильно тянете данные из интента? либо вид `putExtra()` неправильно подобран

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, уже по всякому пробовал и эта же конструкция, в другой части кода, норм работает.

Comment: а вы точку останова не пробовали ставить? чтобы посмотреть что приходит с другой активити?

Comment: a BaseActivity от чего extend?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, попробовал, на выходе `extras` присутствует, в `onResume` запускаемого активити его уже нет.

Comment: @TimurVI, добавил инфо в вопрос.

Comment: `MainActivity` повторно стартует точно через стартактивити? Не через `finish()` или `onBackPressed()` ?

Comment: @RomanK., точно через `startActivity`, а сам интент запускается по кнопке не связанной с `onBackPressed()`

Comment: Пробуйте его доставать в onCreate() и если что расставляйте брейкпоинты и дебажте

Comment: @RomanK., `onCreate()` не вызывается, если активити уже был запущен ранее, потому и пытаюсь достать в `onResume()`

Comment: эм..что?
Вы же делаете новый интент на стартактивити? Он его должен создавать заново и ложить в стек переходов

Comment: @RomanK., не создает, открывает уже запущенный. Хотя это навело меня на мысль, попробую запустить с флагом для нового запуска или очисткой стека.

Comment: `android:launchMode="singleInstance" ` вам это действительно нужно?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Активность с режимами `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` и `"singleTop"`, будучи запущенной ранее, повторно не запускается, а получает вызов [`onNewIntent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity?hl=ru#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)) - в этом методе Вы и получите новый интент с Вашими данными.

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    // делаем что нужно здесь
    ...........................
    // либо меняем интент Activity, чтобы в onResume и далее
    // getIntent() возвращал уже новый
    setIntent(intent);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе добрый человек, это именно то, что было нужно )