# При переходе в приложение по диплинку берутся старые данные

Tags: android, kotlin, deeplink

Я перехожу в приложение при помощи диплинка и передаю в него данные при помощи него же. Диплинк, скажем, такой: myscheme://myhost/addcard?cardId=999&system=mastercard.

Проблема в том, что эти данные передаются только в том случае, если процесс приложения в данный момент не запущен. Если же приложение работает (даже свернуто), то данные даже при переходе по диплинку берутся из уже существующего интента, который был создан ранее при запуске из лаунчера, то есть равны null. Данные беру из активити в onCreate() таким образом:

```
val data = intent.data
val cardId = data?.getQueryParameter("cardId")
val system = data?.getQueryParameter("system")
```

Или если ранее мы перешли в незапущенное приложение при помощи диплинка и передали в него данные `cardId=000&system=visa`, а затем при уже запущенном процессе приложения снова перешли по диплинку с данными `cardId=555&system=mastercard`, то данные будут из первого диплинка, то есть `cardId=000&system=visa`:

Как сделать так, чтобы при переходе по диплинку брались данные из него, даже если процесс приложения уже запущен?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/884195/11515

Comment: Спасибо, и правда